# update the values without refreshing the page

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, controllers, ajax, multi-vendor

We are using following code for button, once we enter the value in textfield and click on "update" button, it will update the value , in the mean time it will refresh the page. But it should update without refreshing the page.

we are updating `Price, Special price, Attributes, quantity` using single update button.

**Complete code to update Price**

```
<input onFocus="showPriceCancel('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>');" 
class="ama1" type = "text" 
id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"

<?php echo Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->formatTxt($products->getPrice(), 
 array('display' => Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL)); ?>

onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" 
value = "<?php echo Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->formatTxt($products->getPrice(), array('display' => Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL)); ?>" style = ""/>


<input type="hidden" name="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="curr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" 
value="<?php echo Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->formatTxt($products->getPrice(), array('display' => Zend_Currency::NO_SYMBOL)); ?>" />


<p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>


<button style="display:none;" id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>

</span>
```

**Script**

```
function hideResetPrice(product_id,priceold) { 

var qtyId='#price_'+ product_id; 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#price_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#price_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valueprice="#valueprice_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#price_reset_button_"+ product_id; 

$wk_jq(resetButton).hide(); 
$wk_jq(valueprice).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currprice).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}


function updateFieldPrice(product_id) 
{ 
var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id; 
var currprice='#curr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>'; 
$price = $wk_jq(priceId).val(); 
$wk_jq(currprice).val($price); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 
parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
```

**controllers.php**

```
public function updateFieldPriceAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));


        try{
        $upd_price = $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

        $product->setPrice($upd_price);
        $product->save();

        echo $price = $product->getPrice();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

**code for saving all fields using Button**

**phtml**

```
<button class="button" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?>" type="button" onclick="changeaction()"  id="mass_update_butn">
    <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Save') ?></span></span>
</button>
```

**script**

```
function changeaction() {
    document.getElementById('formmassdelete').action = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/massupdatesellerpro') ?>";
    document.getElementById('formmassdelete').submit();
}
```

**controllers**

```
public function massupdatesellerproAction(){
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if(!$this->_validateFormKey()){
            $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
        }
        $ids= $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_mass_update');
        $price= $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');

        $i=1;
        foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
            $i=$i+1;
            $qty = $this->getRequest()->getParam('stock'.$i);
            $selllermpassignproduct=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($value);
            $assignqty=isset($selllermpassignproduct['assignqty'])?$selllermpassignproduct['assignqty']:0;
            $newqty=$qty+$assignqty;

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value);
            $product->setPrice($price[$key]);

            $product->save();
            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($value);
            $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
            $stockItem->setData('qty', $newqty);
            $stockItem->save();
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Products has been sucessfully Updated from your account'));
        $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please post your entire form ? so we can see all the fields sent to your controller

Answer (score 1):

In your JS you have this line `document.getElementById('formmassdelete').submit();` it tells your browser to submit the form, hence reloading the page.
If you want to do something without reloading the page and still use a controller action you should use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#example-3).

Comment: Agreed above. However, you can still keep the old logic, just update the 'new' value as well even on a refresh, if that is the reason you want to 'not' refresh.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use AJAX.

If you're using jQuery you can use the following code to trigger your controller:

```
function changeaction() {
    jQuery.ajax( {
            url : "<?php echo $this->getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/massupdatesellerpro') ?>",
            dataType : 'json',
            type : 'get',
            data : {"product_mass_update" :pmu, "price": price, "stock": stock},
            success : function(data) {
            }
        });
}
```

Note: you will have to instantiate the following JavaScript variables with the following values:

- pmu => what corresponds to the product_mass_update parameter in your form
- price => what corresponds to the price parameter in your form
- stock => you will have to update that to add as many parameters as need to match your needs.

Comment: I updated the code, please let me know if you need more infromation

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where in the code updateFieldPrice function is called, so I cannot tell you why your page gets refreshed. There is just no code for that.
Please post the full code of the form with an "Update" button.

Comment: i posted  `updateFieldPrice`  code present in both files, please check complete code in these files.   controller.php : http://pastebin.com/6havFnve
productlist.phtml : http://pastebin.com/JmbHU7G3